# Detect each connection by jsPlumb

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jsplumb

I'm using jsPlumb to create connections between div's in my application.

I was wondering if there is a way to check what elements are connected or not when a person clicks on a button.

```js
jsPlumb.bind("ready", function () {

                    var anEndpointSource = {
                        endpoint: "Rectangle",
                        maxConnections: -1,
                        isSource: true,
                        isTarget: false,
                        anchor: [0, 0.2, 1, 0, 0, -25],
                        paintStyle: { fillStyle: "blue" }
                    };

                    var anEndpointDestination = {
                        endpoint: "Dot",
                        maxConnections: -1,
                        isSource: false,
                        isTarget: true,
                        anchor: [1, 0.2, 1, 0, 0, -25],
                        paintStyle: { fillStyle: "blue" }
                    };
                    var els = document.querySelectorAll(".DTable");
                    var div = $('.DTable');

                    jsPlumb.draggable(els, {
                        dragOptions: ""
                    });


                    jsPlumb.addEndpoint(
                        div,
                        anEndpointSource
                    );

                    jsPlumb.addEndpoint(
                        div,
                        anEndpointDestination
                    );

                });
```

```html
<div id="test" class="DTable" data-Id="1">
        <h4 spellcheck="false"><input placeholder="TableNavn" /></h4>
        <div class="Properties">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Key</td>
                        <td>Column name</td>
                        <td>Type</td>
                        <td>Settings</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr data-Id="1" data-required="No">
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="Key" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control">
                                <option value="int">int</option>
                                <option value="guid">guid</option>
                                <option value="string">string</option>
                                <option value="bool">bool</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="fa fa-2x fa-cogs"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <hr />
            <span class="fa fa-2x fa-plus-circle"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When each div is created a unique attribute `div-Id="Unique"`, so it can get target by class and data-*.

Lets say a person creates 3 divs, and connects div1 and div3. then he press the button and it writes that div1 and div3 is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
var connected = jsPlumb.getConnections();
    $.each(connected, function (e, s) {
         console.log(s.source);
         console.log(s.target);
    })
```